# HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect is trying to send users to the wrong place

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've got a section of code that redirects users to a page when their session times out:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    string szCookieHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
    if ((null != szCookieHeader) && (szCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("SessionTimeout.aspx");
    }
}
```

The problem is that IIS can't find SessionTimeout.aspx because its looking in the wrong place:

```
The file '/site/site/site/site/site/site/Site/SessionTimeout.aspx' does not exist.
```

With more and more "/site/" levels being added as time goes on. I can suppress the problem by creating a tree of ".../site/site/..." and placing an SessionTimeout.aspx in each but this is obviously not a true solution.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried to use ~ ?

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/SessionTimeout.aspx");
```

that will be resolved at runtime with the full url of your site.

Answer (score 6):

Your redirect is relative to the current page.  Add ~/ to the url to have it look at the root of the site.

Your redirect should read:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/SessionTimeout.aspx");
```